# glCopyTexImage*D: How to push data to a single image

Tags: opengl, textures

> "each array layer has a number of faces. Face, layer, and level yields
>   a single image." http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture_Storage

- The glTex--Sub--Image commands allow uploading of data to rectangular regions of the texture image.
- With glCopyTexImage*D you are able to specify the mipmap-level and offsets into the texture array.

The issue I have is that I may be using a more complex texture type (GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY​ or GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_ARRAY​) which can have array layers (and cubefaces for the latter example) how do I calculate the offsets for the specific layer (or face) to get the start of the 2D image I want to replace?

I think that to address the cubeface I bind the texture to a target like GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X​. But I am unsure of both this and the offset calculation of layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What "offset calculation" are you talking about?

Images in array textures and layer-faces in cubemap arrays have ''indices''. There's no offset to calculate. If you want to modify a specific image in the array, you upload to a specific layer/layer-face index.

So if you want to upload to the first image in an array, you set the yoffset/zoffset parameter of glTexSubImage2D/3D to 0 (because arrays use zero-based indices). And you set the height/depth parameter to 1, so that you're only updating one layer.

Comment: Lightening fast as always, clearly I'm just not parsing the terminology correctly. I'll go have another read and rephrase if I'm still being a muppet.

Comment: Arghh why is it so damn obvious once *you* explain it? Sorry, I get it now.